# gcc.exe error in SASM assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly

I am trying to learn assembly and am starting to understand the basics and I found a part of this code online and have been messing with it. Here is the code:

```
%include "io.inc"
prompt1 db "Enter a number: ", 0
prompt2 db "Enter another number: ", 0 
outmsg1 db "You entered ", 0 
outmsg2 db " and ", 0
outmsg3 db ", the sum of these is ", 0
segment .bss  
input1 resd 1 
input2 resd 1
segment .text 
    global _asm_main 
 _asm_main:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging 
    enter 0,0 ; setup routine 
    pusha
    mov eax, prompt1 ; print out prompt 
    call print_string
    call read_int ; read integer 
    mov [input1], eax ; store into input1
    mov eax, prompt2 ; print out prompt
    call print_string
    call read_int ; read integer 
    mov [input2], eax ; store into input2
    mov eax, [input1] ; eax = dword at input1 
    add eax, [input2] ; eax += dword at input2 
    mov ebx, eax ; ebx = eax
    dump_regs 1 ; print out register values
    dump_mem 2, outmsg1, 1 ; print out memory 
    mov eax, outmsg1 
    call print_string ; print out first message 
    mov eax, [input1] 
    call print_int ; print out input1 
    mov eax, outmsg2 
    call print_string ; print out second message 
    mov eax, [input2] 
    call print_int ; print out input2 
    mov eax, outmsg3
    call print_string ; print out third message 
    mov eax, ebx 
    call print_int ; print out sum (ebx) 
    call print_nl ; print new-line
    popa
    mov eax, 0 ; return back to C 
    leave 
    ret
```

I uses SASM compiler and these are the errors:

```
C:\Users\*my user name*\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm:27: error: parser: instruction expected
C:\Users\*my user name*\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm:28: error: parser: instruction expected
gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\*my user name*\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.o: No such file or directory
```

I still do not know assembly well enough to debug this and was wondering if any of you could help me out.

[EDIT] lines 27 and 28 are as follows:

```
dump_regs 1 ; print out register values
dump_mem 2, outmsg1, 1 ; print out memory
```

Comment: Which line are 27 and 28?

Comment: The `io.inc` with SASM's NASM doesn't have the `dump_regs` macro. Th available macros in `io.inc` are listed in the SASM docs: https://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html

Comment: @Michael Petch how would I get a mask library with it dump_regs in it??